# Why useEffect doesn't trigger on document change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am writing custom hook to set new locale every time when the HTML lang attribute changes, but it seems the `useEffect` hook doesn't fire when the `document.documentElement.lang` is changed with javascript. I know how to solve this, my question is why does it behave like this?

```js
export const useLocale = (): LocaleObject => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState<string>(document.documentElement.lang);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLang(document.documentElement.lang);
  }, [document.documentElement.lang]); // useEffect is not triggered when document.documentElement.lang changes

  return locale[lang];
};
```

Comment: it should be `useEffect(() => {setLang(document.documentElement.lang)}, [lang]);`

Comment: Why? Because the change to `document.documentElement.lang` won't trigger the hook. Only a render will trigger the hook, and if `lang` changed the callback will be executed.

Comment: So in order to hook to be triggered there has to be re-render, right? I thought there could be just any change of the provided dependencies and the `useEffect` will be triggered irrespective of rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DennisVash written in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313807/why-useeffect-doesnt-trigger-on-document-change#comment117237461_66313807):

> Why? Because the change to document.documentElement.lang won't trigger
> the hook. Only a render will trigger the hook, and if lang changed the
> callback will be executed.

However, since changing the property actually changes the `lang` attribute value in the DOM, you can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to track the `lang` attribute values.

I've created a custom `useMutationObserver` hook to track mutations in the DOM, and based `useLocale` on it.

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, useState, useCallback } = React;

const useMutationObserver = (domNodeSelector, observerOptions, cb) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const targetNode = document.querySelector(domNodeSelector);
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(cb);
    
    observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
    
    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, [domNodeSelector, observerOptions, cb]);
}

const options = { attributes: true };

const useLocale = () => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState(document.documentElement.lang);
  
  const handler = useCallback(mutationList => { 
    mutationList.forEach(mutation => {
      if(mutation.type !== 'attributes' || mutation.attributeName !== 'lang') return;

      setLang(document.documentElement.lang);
    });
  }, []);
  
  useMutationObserver('html', options, handler);

  return lang; // locale[lang]
};

const Demo = () => {
  const locale = useLocale();

  return <div>{locale}</div>;
};

document.documentElement.lang = 'en'; // base lang

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
);

// example - changing the lang
setTimeout(() => document.documentElement.lang = 'fr', 1000);
setTimeout(() => document.documentElement.lang = 'ru', 3000);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```